# How to take a screenshot of a Wxpython GUI program when menu drops down on menubar

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to capture a screenshot of a wxpython GUI program when the program menu on the menu bar drops down?. I attempted to do this by pressing the print screen key on my keyboard but it didn't work.

Nevertheless, the print screen function key works fine when the menu on the menubar does NOT drop down.

I noticed I can take screenshots of other GUI programs on my system when their menu options are seen .

If this is possible, what codes can I place in my program to facilitate a successful screenshot when any menu is showing?

Comment: Maybe a little bit over the top but if you are really unable to screenshot, then videorecord the action and then save the frame where it is open from the video as a photo.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried "Shift-prt scr" on my Windows 8.1 to capture a screen with a menu shown (used the wxPython demo) and it worked for me.

You can also use a screen capture utility, e.g. I often use IrfanView, to do this, with it I set a timer to capture things which go away when the window looses focus.

Comment: I am coding in a Debian Linux OS...Nevertheless, I will review IrfanView

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu using Mate under Applications--> Accessories there is a Take Screen shot option.
The actual command is `mate-screenshot --interactive`
this allows you Full screen, Current window or Selected area, with a "Grab delay", I found it particularly useful documenting wxpython, although you will have to drag the window to a size to accommodate the full menu or you end up with it cut off.
Note: `gnome-screenshot --interactive`, is another alternative.

Edit:
Have you checked out pyscreenshot?
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot

It claims the following usage:
Example:

import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

```
# fullscreen
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()

# part of the screen
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,510,510)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
im.show()
```